# Not getting "from" attribute in facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, facebook-permissions

I'm using **facebook API v9.0** to get posts and comments associated with it using the **page token**.

The issue is such that I'm unable to get the **'from'** attribute or in other words, the author of the comments in the response. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, please advice.

The cURL request is as below: `995833924237049` is the post_id

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/995833924237049/comments?fields=from&access_token={access_token}"
```

The response is as below from Graph API Explorer:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_819251442244461"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998774397276335"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998772833943158"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998781380608970"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998776877276087"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998782583942183"
    },
    {
      "id": "995833924237049_998781987275576"
    },
    ...
]}
```

The permissions I have currently are as below:-

- email
- pages_show_list
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_posts

Comment: Seems an open question https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/835915183559820/